# Borderlands on PS3 online?

Tags: ps3, borderlands

Is there any way to play Borderlands PS3 online? I understand the game used the now-defunct Gamespy for online matchmaking. When I go to multiplayer I just get a blank screen. Is there any patch or workaround for playing this game online?

Comment: I know a patch was released for the Steam version... have you tried starting the game whilst signed into the internet?

Comment: Yes, my console is connected to the internet and logged in to PSN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### YES

**As of 2/2/2015, Borderlands multiplayer functionality on PS3 [has been restored](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1310/borderlands-1-playstation-3-multiplayer-functionality-restored).**

From the Article:

> ...Now, we're happy to announce that multiplayer will be restored to Borderlands 1 on PS3 today in both North America and Europe (and Japan is coming soon!).
>
> Upon launching Borderlands 1 on PS3, you'll be prompted to download an update that enables the new matchmaking system...<snip>
>
> If you have any trouble, visit http://support.gearbox.com.

Thanks to everyone for your patience as we worked to find a solution, and special thanks to the folks at 22nd Century Toys for helping to make this happen!

Comment: Thanks. Alas it seems PS3 is the poor cousin and nothing has been done for this popular platform.

Comment: @MarkyMark - I imagine the problem is the PS3 doesn't have the equivalent of 'steamworks' servers, meaning 2k would have to find another third-party hosting provider or host it themselves - either way nothing official is announced yet (and at least theyre investigating, a lot of companies would drop a game the minute it stopped being profitable)

Comment: Looks like we jumped the gun by 3 days, as it was restored on the 2nd :)